# Decode a String (UTF?)

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, decode

Do you know what sort of encoding is being used in the string below? For some context, its from the output I get from twitters standard search api response.

'los angelesu20145 days privu00e9 allianceu2019s fashion presentationnnwith baekhyun'

Finally, do you know of a way for me to easily decode this via python?

Comment: If it starts with a `u` it's unicode

Comment: Can you add the output of `print(repr(example_string))` to the question please?

Comment: Lost backslash(es). Try `print('los angeles\u20145 days priv\u00e9 alliance\u2019s fashion presentation\n\nwith baekhyun')`. Here `\u2014` = em dash,  `\u2019` = right single quotation mark and `\n` = ASCII Linefeed (LF).